# CodeIgniter Pagination Not Work At Other Page

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I started a web application in CI 3.0, everything working smooth, I got my pagination working, but there is a problem which I cannot figure out...

My Model

```
//Model
    function jumlah(){
        return $this->db->count_all('buku');
    }

    function fetch_buku($limit,$start){
      $this->db->limit($limit,$start);
      $query=$this->db->get('buku');

      if($query->num_rows()>0){
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
          $data[]=$row;
        }
        return $data;
      }
      return false;
    }
```

My Controller

```
//Controller
    function index(){

        //load data
        $data['title']="Data Buku";

        $config['base_url']=site_url('anggota/index/');
        $total_row=$this->m_buku->jumlah();
        $config['total_rows']=$total_row;
        $config['per_page']=$this->limit;
        $config['use_page_numbers']=TRUE;
        $config['uri_segment']=3;
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $page=($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3):0;;

        $data['buku']=$this->m_buku->fetch_buku($config['per_page'],$page);
        $data['pagination']=$this->pagination->create_links();
            $data['message']='';
            $this->template->display('buku/index',$data);
    }
```

My view

```
//View
    

    <?php echo $message;?>
        <Table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>No.</td>
            <td>Image</td>
            <td>Kode Buku</td>
            <td>Judul</td>
            <td>Pengarang</td>
            <td>Klasifikasi</td>
            <td colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php $no=0; foreach($buku as $row ): $no++;?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $no;?></td>
        <td><img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/'.$row->image);?>" height="100px" width="100px"></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->kode_buku;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->judul;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->pengarang;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->klasifikasi;?></td>
        <td><a href="<?php echo site_url('buku/edit/'.$row->kode_buku);?>"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a></td>
        <td><a href="#" class="hapus" kode="<?php echo $row->kode_buku;?>"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</Table>
        
        <?php echo $pagination;?>
```

My problem is when I load other page, data can't display at that page. But data can display in first page.

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

**In Controller**

```
$total_row = $this->m_buku->jumlah();

$config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'anggota/index/'; # make sure site is load without index.php
$config['total_rows'] = $total_row;
$config['per_page'] = '12'; # provide some number here
$config['uri_segment'] = 2; # this should be 2. If index.php is there then 3

$this->pagination->initialize($config);

$page = ($this->uri->segment(2)) ? $this->uri->segment(2) : 0;

$data['links'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
```

**In View**

```
echo $links
```

> > > **Make sure site is load without index.php**

Answer (score 0):

If you set `$config['use_page_numbers']` to TRUE than it will translate the offset. Try to change the value to FALSE. Let say your `$config['per_page']` is 10 than it should display something like this in your URL: `anggota/index/`, `anggota/index/10`, `anggota/index/20`. If set to TRUE than your URL may look like this `anggota/index/1`, `anggota/index/2`, `anggota/index/3` etc.